# .net using and reaching public value

Tags: asp.net, .net

I wrote this code in .NET. When I want to change ‘s’ by clicking button2, it doesn’t change. I mean after clicking button2 and then I click Button1 to see the changes but nothing changes. How can I change and access the value of ‘s’ properly. What am I doing wrong?

```
public string s;

public void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Label1.Text = s;
}

public void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    s = TextBox1.Text;  
}
```

Comment: `s` is not a property, it's a field. If you want to make it a property you should write : `public string s { get; set; }`

Comment: Is this ASP.NET? If So, you may be running into page lifecycle issues. Each request is its own instance of the class, so your instance field is different for each request. You would need to persist this in something that spans a page's lifecycle, like session state.

Comment: Make sure Button1_Click is indeed subscribed to the Button1.Clicked event. Call MessageBox.Show('Hello World') inside Button1_Click() http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa335415(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: Is it *ASP.NET* or *WinForms* or *WPF*? Add appropriate tag to your question

Comment: this is ASP.NET webpage

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to understand how web applications work.

In each post back an instance of the class that handles the page is loaded, so when you click on button 1, the page does a post back and loads again, so this way the variable s isn't loaded with your content.

To make this code work, you need to save the S values on the page viewstate.

try replacing "public string s;" with this:

```
public string s
{
    get {  return (string)ViewState["myValue"]; }
    set [ ViewState["myValue"] = value };

}
```

More Information about Page Life Cycle at: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472(v=vs.100).aspx